# How do I import sage 'modules' into a .py file in order to run the code in Spyder

Tags: python, import, module, sage

First of all, english is not my first language so sorry for the mistakes.
So I'm trying to implement the GNFS in python. To do so, I'd like to use sagemath. However, I run into some issues. Here's what happened :

0. General informations : I use Windows and I downloaded SageMath 9.2 [here](http://www-ftp.lip6.fr/pub/math/sagemath/win/index.html), i.e. directly with an installer.
   My goal is to run the line :

```
dickman_rho(log(10**10) / log(10**3))              [1]
```

So my major issue is to access the `dickman_rho` function

1. My first attempt was to just to plus line [1] into sagemath 9.2 console and it absolutely worked ! Same thing if I use a `sagetest.py` file with the code :

```
print(dickman_rho(log(10**10) / log(10**3)))
```

And I type, into the sage console :

```
load("PATH\sagetest.py")
```

However, i would like to be able to write a `.py` file and compile it directly (I use Anaconda 3 Spyder) without using the sage console. I figured that, in order to do this, I have to somehow import the sage 'module'

2. So I searched for the module all over my computer but I wasn't able to find it. I finally figured that it came from the way I installed SageMath and thus I went [here](http://www-ftp.lip6.fr/pub/math/sagemath/src/index.html) to download the source.
   I extracted the `tar.gz` into a separate folder and I was left with the source code.
   I then run, in the sage core, the line :

```
import_statements(dickman_rho)
```

And sure enough, I get the answer :

```
from sage.functions.transcendental import dickman_rho
```

So I copied this line into my `sagetest.py`file, which now consists of :

```
from sage.functions.transcendental import dickman_rho
from math import log
print(dickman_rho(log(10**10) / log(10**3)))
```

and... it failed. I get this error message :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sage.functions.transcendental'
```

3. At this point, the sage 'library' (the folder with all the source codes) was still on my desktop so I figured that my system didn't know where to find it. So I copied it into  `PATH\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages` where all the other modules (like sympy, scipy, ...) are. I run ```sagetest.py`` and... it also failed. But this time, the error message was :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sage.rings.complex_number'
```

4. At first that error message didn't make any sense whatsoever because I never tried to import `sage.rings.complex_number`. But then I went and looked into the code, and in particular the file `PATH\sage\functions\transcendental.py`. It contains the instruction :

```
import sage.rings.complex_field as complex_field
```

I then went to find the `PATH\sage\ring\complex_field.py` file to see what was the issue but... this file doesn't exist ! 
All I was able to find was `PATH\sage\ring\complex_field.pyx` and `PATH\sage\ring\complex_field.pxd`

5. So I went online to look for a method to import a `.pyx`, and I found that using this :

```
import pyximport
pyximport.install()
```

at the begining of my code would help. So my file `sagetes.py` now consists of :

```
import pyximport
pyximport.install()
from sage.functions.transcendental import dickman_rho
from math import log
print(dickman_rho(log(10**10) / log(10**3)))
```

And I get this very long error message (I copy-pasted it here completely in cas it turns out to be usefull but it is very long) :

```
FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sage\rings\complex_number.pxd
  tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from sage.libs.mpfr.types cimport mpfr_rnd_t, mpfr_t

cimport sage.rings.ring
cimport sage.structure.element
from cypari2.types cimport GEN
^
------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sage\rings\real_mpfr.pxd:5:0: 'cypari2\types.pxd' not found

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from sage.libs.mpfr.types cimport mpfr_rnd_t, mpfr_t

cimport sage.rings.ring
cimport sage.structure.element
from cypari2.types cimport GEN
^
------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sage\rings\real_mpfr.pxd:5:0: 'cypari2\types\GEN.pxd' not found

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        return <RealNumber>(RealNumber.__new__(RealNumber, self._parent))
    cpdef _add_(self, other)
    cpdef _mul_(self, other)
    cpdef _mod_(self, right)
    cdef _set(self, x, int base)
    cdef _set_from_GEN_REAL(self, GEN g)
                                 ^
------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sage\rings\real_mpfr.pxd:28:34: 'GEN' is not a type identifier

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from sage.libs.mpmath.utils cimport mpfr_to_mpfval
from sage.rings.integer_ring import ZZ

from sage.misc.superseded import deprecated_function_alias

cimport gmpy2
       ^
------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sage\rings\complex_number.pyx:49:8: 'gmpy2.pxd' not found

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from sage.rings.integer_ring import ZZ

from sage.misc.superseded import deprecated_function_alias

cimport gmpy2
gmpy2.import_gmpy2()
    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sage\rings\complex_number.pyx:50:5: cimported module has no attribute 'import_gmpy2'

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
            elif isinstance(real, list) or isinstance(real, tuple):
                re, imag = real
                real = re
            elif isinstance(real, complex):
                real, imag = real.real, real.imag
            elif type(real) is gmpy2.mpc:
                                   ^
------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sage\rings\complex_number.pyx:193:36: cimported module has no attribute 'mpc'

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
                re, imag = real
                real = re
            elif isinstance(real, complex):
                real, imag = real.real, real.imag
            elif type(real) is gmpy2.mpc:
                real, imag = (<gmpy2.mpc>real).real, (<gmpy2.mpc>real).imag
                              ^
------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sage\rings\complex_number.pyx:194:31: 'mpc' is not a type identifier

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
                re, imag = real
                real = re
            elif isinstance(real, complex):
                real, imag = real.real, real.imag
            elif type(real) is gmpy2.mpc:
                real, imag = (<gmpy2.mpc>real).real, (<gmpy2.mpc>real).imag
                                                      ^
------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sage\rings\complex_number.pyx:194:55: 'mpc' is not a type identifier

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
            sage: CF = ComplexField(70)
            sage: y = CF(x)
            sage: x == mpc(y)
            True
        """
        return gmpy2.GMPy_MPC_From_mpfr(self.__re, self.__im)
                   ^
------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sage\rings\complex_number.pyx:683:20: cimported module has no attribute 'GMPy_MPC_From_mpfr'
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 214, in load_module
    so_path = build_module(module_name, pyxfilename, pyxbuild_dir,

  File "C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 186, in build_module
    so_path = pyxbuild.pyx_to_dll(pyxfilename, extension_mod,

  File "C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyxbuild.py", line 102, in pyx_to_dll
    dist.run_commands()

  File "C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)

  File "C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 186, in run
    _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)

  File "C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
    self.build_extensions()

  File "C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 195, in build_extensions
    _build_ext.build_ext.build_extensions(self)

  File "C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions
    self._build_extensions_serial()

  File "C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 474, in _build_extensions_serial
    self.build_extension(ext)

  File "C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 528, in build_extension
    objects = self.compiler.compile(sources,

  File "C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 327, in compile
    self.initialize()

  File "C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 224, in initialize
    vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)

  File "C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 126, in _get_vc_env
    raise DistutilsPlatformError("Unable to find vcvarsall.bat")

DistutilsPlatformError: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\leobo\OneDrive\Bureau\sagetest.py", line 3, in <module>
    from sage.functions.transcendental import dickman_rho

  File "C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sage\functions\transcendental.py", line 21, in <module>
    import sage.rings.complex_field as complex_field

  File "C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sage\rings\complex_field.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .complex_number import ComplexNumber, RRtoCC

  File "C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 459, in load_module
    module = load_module(fullname, self.path,

  File "C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 231, in load_module
    raise exc.with_traceback(tb)

  File "C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 214, in load_module
    so_path = build_module(module_name, pyxfilename, pyxbuild_dir,

  File "C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 186, in build_module
    so_path = pyxbuild.pyx_to_dll(pyxfilename, extension_mod,

  File "C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyxbuild.py", line 102, in pyx_to_dll
    dist.run_commands()

  File "C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)

  File "C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 186, in run
    _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)

  File "C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
    self.build_extensions()

  File "C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 195, in build_extensions
    _build_ext.build_ext.build_extensions(self)

  File "C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions
    self._build_extensions_serial()

  File "C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 474, in _build_extensions_serial
    self.build_extension(ext)

  File "C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 528, in build_extension
    objects = self.compiler.compile(sources,

  File "C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 327, in compile
    self.initialize()

  File "C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 224, in initialize
    vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)

  File "C:\Users\leobo\anaconda3\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 126, in _get_vc_env
    raise DistutilsPlatformError("Unable to find vcvarsall.bat")

ImportError: Building module sage.rings.complex_number failed: ['distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat\n']
```

So from what I understood :

- there are a bunch of Cython (what is that ??) errors
- there is this `DistutilsPlatformError: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat` error message (what is a `.bat` file ??)
- and this message occured a second time at the end :

```
ImportError: Building module sage.rings.complex_number failed:
['distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat\n']
```

I am now completely lost. I don't understand anything from this error message so I don't have the slightest idea of where to go next to try and fix it. So if someone knows what is Cython, what is a `.bat` file, and more generally how to import a `.pyx` module, I would be very thankfull !

Comment: Sage is still not perfectly integrated with the standard Python or Anaconda environment. Is there a reason why you want to run you script from Anaconda? If not, it'll be much easier to launch your script by running `sage sagetest.py`. This way Sage's Python rather than Anaconda's will be used.

Comment: I've had the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sage.rings.complex_number'` error before. I never understood it, but I found that the easy way to make it go away is to replace your import statement with `from sage.all import dickman_rho`, or simply `from sage.all import *` (not very Pythonic, admittedly).

Comment: Yes there is a reason. If I was doing it just for fun, I wouldn't carr and I would use the sage console. However, this is a code I'm working on for an exam, and using the sage console wouldn't be appreciated at all.

Comment: Thanks for the solution ! I'll try it, I really hope it will work

Comment: @LucaDeFeo I tried it and run into yet another issue... My ```sagetest.py``` file is now : 
```from sage.all import dickman_rho
print(dickman_rho(log(10**10) / log(10**3)))```
And the error message is : 
```AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'uname'```
This error come from the line :
```var('UNAME',               os.uname()[0])```
in the file ```PATH\sage\env.py```

.......

Comment: You may have seriously screwed up the Sage installation by moving it to another location on the file system. I recommend you restart the installation from scratch.

Comment: @LucaDeFeo actually after looking it up it is because os.uname exists only on Linux and I use Windows... so I don't think Ill be able to solve this issue.